# Data Loading - Problems with quotation marks

Tags: oracle-apex

Thank you for any help in advance.

Version: Apex 4.2

I am using the data loading wizard in an Apex application, and facing issues when trying to load data with quotation marks (9"). I think it is trying to find another quotation mark which is causing it to join multiple records to load together.

I have tried using a transformation rule, which works and successfully replaces the quotation for the word 'inch', however its like this does not take affect until after the data is loaded, as still face the same issue. Its as if the rule files after the data has loaded?

Has anyone else faced these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Oracles way to qoute Literals?
For example:

```
DECLARE
  sometext varchar2(255);
BEGIN
  sometext := q'[9"]';
  dbms_output.put_line(sometext);
END;
```

The output then is: 9"

You can look it up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm) for reference.